# How to get a Linux MAC address from a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, linux, mac-address

i have a two systems, one Windows, one Linux. Both are connected to a local network. How can I get the Linux MAC address from Windows?

Answer (score 2):

On a windows box, you will need to go to the command prompt. Then, you can either type `arp -a` to get a list of all the MAC addresses of all the computers you know about, or you can do `arp -a <internal IP of linux box>` and get the MAC address for a specific IP address.

On my windows box;

```
C:\Users\sg>arp -a 192.168.0.8

Interface: 192.168.0.6 --- 0xb
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.0.8           08-00-27-3a-b4-f8     dynamic
```

And just to make sure...

```
[sg@sg sdf]$ /sbin/ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:3A:B4:F8
          inet addr:192.168.0.8  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe3a:b4f8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:180424 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:225990 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:45063805 (42.9 MiB)  TX bytes:18822112 (17.9 MiB)
```

Answer (score 1):

`arp -a IPaddr` works but only after you've connected to that device (ping will do)

i.e. if you reboot your machine and do `arp -a IPaddr` it will say "not found".

If you then ping `IPaddr` then repeat `arp` it will show the IP, given there is no router between the two else it will show you the router's MAC.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *192.168.0.77* is the ip address of your linux system, try the following command:

```
arp -a 192.168.0.77
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to you computer using telnet, then after connection is successful try to run this command in your telnet window, this will give you the mac address of the machine to which you are connected.
`

> ifconfig

for linux

or

> ipconfig/all

for windows

`